# Rails and Mongoid :: Converting Strings to Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I collect tags in a nice javascript UI widget. It then takes all the tags and passes them to the server as tag1,tag2,tag3,etc in one text_field input. The server receives them:

```
params[:event][:tags] = params[:event][:tags].split(',') # convert to array
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
```

Is there a better way to convert the string to the array? It seems like a code smell. I have to put this both in update and in the new actions of the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this in the model:

I have seldom experience on mongoid. The following would work in active record (the only difference is the write_attribute part)

```
class Event
  def tags=(value_from_form)
    value_from_form = "" unless value_from_form.respond_to(:split)

    write_attribute(:tags, value_from_form.split(','))
  end
end
```

---

On the other hand, for consistency, you may want to do the following:

```
class Event
  def tags_for_form=(value_from_form)
    value_from_form = "" unless value_from_form.respond_to(:split)

    self.tags = value_from_form.split(',')
  end

  def tags_for_form
    self.tags
  end

  # no need to change tags and tags= methods. and tags and tags= methods would return an array and accept an array respectively
end
```

In the first case (directly overwriting the `tags=` method), `tags=` accepts a string but `tags` returns an array.

In the second case, `tags_for_form=` and `tags_for_form` accepts and returns string, while `tags=` and `tags` accepts and returns array.

Comment: I don't understand the second example, how can tag= and tags accept arrays this way? it also doesn't work.

Comment: In the second way, you don't directly use `tags` in your form. ie `f.text_field :tags_for_form`. When the object received the value, it split it and store the array into `tags=`. So `tags=` expected to accept an array (if you assign a string to it, it will fail).

Answer (score 1):

I just create another model attribute that wraps the tags attribute like so:

```
class Event
  def tags_list=(tags_string)
    self.tags = tags_string.split(',').map(&:strip)
  end

  def tags_list
    self.tags.join(',')
  end

end
```

In your form, just read/write the tags_list attribute which will always accept, or return a preformated string.  (The `.map(:strip)` part simply removes spaces on the ends in case the tags get entered with spaces:  `tag1, tag2, tag3`.

Answer (score 0):

PeterWong's answer misses the '?' from the respond_to() method;

```
  class Event
    def tags=(value_from_form)
      value_from_form = "" unless value_from_form.respond_to?(:split)

      write_attribute(:tags, value_from_form.split(','))
    end
  end
```

Comment: This should be added to PeterWong answer as improvement, rather than an answer itself.

Comment: What should I do about the rule that an edit must be at least 6 characters?

Comment: Then check out this meta solution: [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)